# Display one TextView in bottom android

Tags: android

In my application, i want to display one TextView in bottom of the Screen with copyright note.

I used following xml code.

In my code TextView couldn't display in bottom of the screen.

I suppose I'm not doing right but I know why.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#bfceee"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:inputType=""
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
        android:background="#EAEAAE"
        android:text="@string/send"
        android:textColor="#5C3317"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="150sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Copyright"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this `android:layout_below="@+id/btnSend"`.

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Copyright"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnSend"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:text="Hi"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

If you want to bottom of the screen then use

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in textView instead of gravity-

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use gravity, use:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

See [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Here i have used LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout becz i have seen top margin which not proper work on various  devices so i have implement weight in LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#bfceee"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/name"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/rt2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="20sp" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSend"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#EAEAAE"
                android:text="@string/send"
                android:textColor="#5C3317"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:width="150sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Copyright"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```